# TeamCity don't trigger automatic build

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity

I'm dumb with continuous integration and noticed a behavior that does not seem right..

I'm using Mercurial with TeamCity. When I push changes the TeamCity detect the changes but don't run the build automatically. This is correct behavior? He should not detect the changes and run the build automatically?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Triggers are not added to build configurations by default in TeamCity.  You'll need to go to the settings for the configuration and click on "Build Triggers" then "Add Trigger".  The type of trigger I believe you are looking for is a "VCS Trigger".

The documentation for this feature can be found [here](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/Configuring+Build+Triggers).

Answer (score 1):

I believe my issues was misunderstanding what was needed in Branch Filters. I thought I was supposed to enter the GIT refs I wanted to have builds triggered from

This wasn't working for me

```
+:refs/heads/*
-:refs/heads/releases/6.7.3
-:refs/heads/releases/6.8.30
-:refs/heads/releases/6.8.32
-:refs/heads/releases/6.8.34
```

And this is what finally figured out (I think) is that it is asking for the branch names inside TeamCity itself (the help text says "Newline-delimited set of rules in the form of +|-:logical branch name")

This worked for me, to trigger builds from the  branch (GIT ref refs/heads/master for me, look back in your VCS Root setup) and all other branches except those labeled "releases/6.7.3", "releases/6.8.30", "releases/6.8.32" and "releases/6.8.34"

```
+:*
-:releases/6.7.3
-:releases/6.8.30
-:releases/6.8.32
-:releases/6.8.34
```